# Publish binary file to maven artifactory along with JAR files using Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am trying to publish a Java library to artifactory using Jenkins. Currently, it is only publishing .jar files to artifactory. I have a binary file (.bin) that I want to publish along with the .jar files. Does anyone know what I need to insert into my POM file to make this work?

For example, I want file structure in  artifactory to look like this:

```
test-0.1.jar
test.bin
...
```

Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>Test Lib </name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- Avoid Java 8's strict doc generator-->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>disable-java8-doclint</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Would this work? https://debugnotes.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/adding-an-additional-jar-file-to-a-maven-build-configuration-file-for-a-spring-mvc-project-pom-xml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build helper maven plugin allows you to attach additional artifacts, see

https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html

under "Attach additional artifacts to your project" or

https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to verify this locally? For example, will the target folder include the .bin in the root along with the .jar files?

Comment: The bin should be in the target folder, and if you do `mvn clean install` it should go to the local repository as well.